# CakePHP 1.3 - Radio label without legend?

Tags: php, forms, cakephp, radio-button

In CakePHP 1.3 for most form inputs I'm able to add a label with the option `'label' => 'MyLabel'`, however the radio button input works a bit differently. It uses a legend and fieldset to organize the buttons and the label for the buttons. Is there a way to remove the legend and fieldset (using `'legend => false'`) while at the same time adding the regular label that most other input use? Specifically in the same format that the other inputs do it? For example, something like:

```
$this->Form->input('active1', array('type' => 'radio', 'options' => array(1=>'Yes', 0=>'No'), 'label' => 'Active', 'legend' => false));
```

This however completely removes the label. Is there a way to leave the label in with an option? Or do I have to create a custom function to do this for me? Thank you much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is not a way to use the standard label option with a radio button, but it is easy to add in your view without the use of a custom function:

```
<label>MyLabel</label>
<?php echo $this->Form->radio('...
```